# Probability of choosing an item from box A but not from box B

Tags: probability

$\frac{2}{8}$ items from box A are green and $\frac{3}{5}$ items from box B are green. If one item is chosen from each box, what is the probability of choosing a green item and a nongreen item?

I'm having some trouble understanding how to combine these two probabilities. The chance of choosing a green item from one box is $\frac{2}{8}$ or $\frac{3}{5}$, and the chance of not choosing a green item from the other box is $\frac{6}{8}$ or $\frac{2}{5}$. Choosing from one box means the other box must be chosen from next. How would you approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities to be considered here -

1. You choose a green object from A AND a non-green object from B.

OR

2. You choose a non-green object from A AND a green object from B.

When you have AND, you multiply the probabilities of the independent events and when you have OR, you add them.

So, Ans = [ (Prob of choosing a Green Object from A)* (Prob of choosing a Non-Green Object from B) ] + [ (Prob of choosing a Non-Green Object from A)*(Prob of choosing a Green Object from B) ]

= (2/8 * 2/5) + (6/8 * 3/5) = 11/20

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it up! I was having trouble connecting these two possibilities.

Comment: Happy to help :)